# Como conferir se o servidor está enviando conteúdo usando compactação GZIP?

Tags: http, aplicação-web, gzip

Existe algum recurso do navegador para conferir se o servidor está enviando conteúdo (HTML, JS, JSON, CSS, etc.) usando compactação GZIP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a extensão do google chamada pagespeed: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

Mas de uma maneira rápida... Se você utiliza o Google Chrome aperte F12 e você será levado ao *DeveloperTools* (uma pequena janelinha em baixo do seu browser). Nela você irá até a aba Network e lá você verá todos os requests feitos para o seu website, procure pela chave **Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate**.

Se isso existir seu site usa o GZIP :D

Update:

No Response Headers existe a chave Content-Encoding:gzip lá deverá constar o gzip.

Comment: A minha dúvida é justamente porque o `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` **sempre** aparece na aba *network*, mesmo quando não está usando.

Comment: Ok vamos lá.... No Response Headers existe a chave **Content-Encoding:gzip** ? Eu esqueci de especificar essa parte.

Comment: Agora achei, é no Response mesmo. Valeu a força. Recomendo que você atualize a resposta com a informação.